# Retrieve DataTable Result object from Nested JSON response

Tags: c#, json, datatable, dataset

I have a json resposne from web (restapi) in which datatable is parsed and converted into json and sent as a resposne from the server. I need to access and retrieve that datatable and data and show in winform grid view. I am having issue accessing and deserializing properly this element from json response.

Here is an example of json response:

```
{
  "api_version": "1.07",
  "app_option": "KOM_KOMITENTI",
  "checksum": "FE1A57ACCBD1EBF981B80344B88AE80B",
  "data": "{\"databaseattachment\": \"{\\\"count\\\": 1,\\\"_class_name\\\": \\\"Tapidatabaseattachment\\\",\\\"items\\\": [{\\\"fields\\\": {\\\"count\\\": 10,\\\"_class_name\\\": \\\"Tapitablefields\\\",\\\"items\\\": [{\\\"name\\\": \\\"sif_firme\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"naziv\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"jmbg\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"adresa\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"mesto\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"tip_firme\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"racun\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"mat_broj\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"C\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"clanova\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"N\\\"},{\\\"name\\\": \\\"saldo\\\",\\\"type\\\": \\\"N\\\"}]},\\\"rows\\\": {\\\"count\\\": 9600,\\\"_class_name\\\": \\\"Tapitablerows\\\",\\\"items\\\": [{\\\"sif_firme\\\": \\\"900010\\\",\\\"naziv\\\": \\\"JanoÅ¡eviÄ‡ Jasminka\\\",\\\"adresa\\\": \\\"Milinka KuÅ¡iÄ‡a 1\\\",\\\"mesto\\\": \\\"Ivanjica\\\",\\\"tip_firme\\\": \\\"01\\\",},{\\\"sif_firme\\\": \\\"900020\\\",\\\"naziv\\\": \\\"ObrenoviÄ‡ DuÅ¡an\\\",\\\"adresa\\\": \\\"Milinka KuÅ¡iÄ‡a 1\\\",\\\"mesto\\\": \\\"Ivanjica\\\",\\\"tip_firme\\\": \\\"01\\\",},{\\\"sif_firme\\\": \\\"900030\\\",\\\"naziv\\\": \\\"RistiÄ‡ Danijela\\\",\\\"adresa\\\": \\\"Milinka KuÅ¡iÄ‡a 3\\\",\\\"mesto\\\": \\\"Ivanjica\\\",\\\"tip_firme\\\": \\\"01\\\",\\\"clanova\\\": 2,\\\"saldo\\\": 31932.7},{\\\"sif_firme\\\": \\\"900040\\\",\\\"naziv\\\": \\\"RistiÄ‡ Ratomir\\\",\\\"adresa\\\": \\\"Milinka KuÅ¡iÄ‡a 3\\\",\\\"mesto\\\": \\\"Ivanjica\\\",\\\"tip_firme\\\": \\\"01\\\",},\\\"table_name\\\": \\\"listakupaca\\\"}]}\\r\\n\",\"database_format\": \"PLAIN_OBJ\",\"error_state\": \"ok\",\"exec_date_time\": \"2018-09-11T11:49:58+02:00\",\"paging_page_len\": 9600,\"paging_rec_count\": 9600,\"paging_selected_page\": 1,\"status\": \"Ok\",\"_class_name\": \"Tapikom_komitentiresult\"}",
  "disk": "d:\\DISK\\P",
  "encoding": "PLAIN",
  "error_state": "ok",
  "instance_id": "743edba3f9f123b",
  "job": "kom",
  "poslovna_godina": 2018,
  "pozicija": "01",
  "referent": "0002",
  "req_id": "DOTEST_4S60QRPEI",
  "result_error_state": "ok",
  "session_id": "53744862e8cc84e7",
  "sif_firme": "0000",
  "_class_name": "Tapiresponseenvelope"
}
```

I need to access "data" element, and "databaseattachment" specifically in which datatable is defined with data retrieved from server.

Trust me, I have researched issue and topic here on stackoverflow and over the net, tried couple of example with converting directly json to datatable using newtonsoft.json. Read a lot of examples about Deserializing JSON, creating required classes thats gonna represent that element - object, but still I have issues because it seems in this json response there are additional parameters that "explains" datatable items, columns and rows with their specific properties and field types.

I tried to parse json object:

```
string mResponseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(mResponse);
JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(mResponseString);
```

I can see the elements in it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCKJh.png

It seems that still I have to access one more level to obtain data from databaseattachment element or to parsed additionaly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA1U1.png

It seems to me that this is some kind of datatable template which is parsed in json and sent with data in response, which seems like a standard way of converting data, but could not find an example that explains this specific case.

How do I access this element - object in json and parse it correctly to be able later to convert into datatable and pass as datasource for gridview?

Comment: I checked your JSON, and it looks like there are errors in JSON. It's not well formed. I'd recommend you to carefully validate it manually.

Comment: have you tried jsonResponse.data.databaseattachment?

Comment: You need to update your json string for data fields.Data  field also contain one child json string.so, you need to create a models for this and deserialization the update string.

Comment: @TiberSeptim thanks for feedback, its not well formed probably because I manually truncated data result for this example, because there are a lot of records.

Arun, can you provide me more details what you mean? I have tried this but it seems the elements are not recognized just like that notation. I can not type that because jsonResposne is not aware of response elements until runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to extract the needed data from json response. Thought might be useful as an answer for someone, who can have similar issue. The problem was that returned data is deeply nested within "data" element, and it is parsed as json object, but inside that object it can be an json array, than another set of json objects and json arrays.

Maybe my solution is not the best one, and its a little bit awkward but I managed it in the end. Had to go through couple of iteration before getting desired element with data for datatable.

```
string mResponseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mResponse);

JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(mResponseString);
string data = (string)jsonResponse["data"];

JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(data);
string databaseattachment = (string)jsonData["databaseattachment"];

JObject jsonDataAttachment = JObject.Parse(databaseattachment);
JArray jaDAItems = (JArray)jsonDataAttachment["items"];
string rows = jaDAItems.First["rows"].ToString();

JObject jaDAItemsRows = JObject.Parse(rows);
JArray jaDARowsItems = (JArray)jaDAItemsRows["items"];

DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jaDARowsItems.ToString());
```